# wordpress ignores formatting when using template tags in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am using the following code to create a shortcode for use in the WYSIWYG.

```
function consultants( $atts, $content = null ) {

$output = '';
$consultant_query = new WP_Query('post_type=consultants&showposts=10');
if ($consultant_query->have_posts()) :
$output .= '<div class="col-md-12">';
while ($consultant_query->have_posts()) : $consultant_query->the_post();

$output .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 kam-tile-own-bg"><h1>' .the_title().      '</h1> ';

 if(has_post_thumbnail())
{

$output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'wpbs-featured-avatar');
} else {
$output .= '
<img class="kam-avatar" width="62" height="62"   src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/avatar@2x.jpg" class="attachment-featured_image  wp-post-image" alt="" />'; }
 $output .= '</div>';

endwhile;
$output .= '</div>';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); 

return $output;

}
```

The code works fine - HOWEVER it fails on the `.the_title().` it throws this at the top of the page it has no respect for the  tags or the  in which it is contained.

Many thanks

Comment: Better post here... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `the_title();` use `get_the_title();`

Comment: How can I stop php from stripping the `/` from the URL in the following php?

    `$output .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 kam-tile-own-bg style="background-image: url('.$url.');"><h1>' .get_the_title(). '</h1><p>' .get_the_content(). '</p>';`